# JAVA Square Footage Calculation

Tags: java

I have to Write a program in Java that will take the dimensions of two different homes and calculate the total square footage. The program will then compare the two values and print out a line of text appropriately stating whether it is larger or smaller than the other one.

I am not sure where to even begin. I am new to Java and have only done a Hello World

Comment: have you thought about how you're going to represent things like your home dimensions? Are you going to make them rectangular homes or allow for more complex shapes?

Comment: do you have to get input from user?

Comment: Begin with baby steps. Decompose the problem into steps (input, process, output). Start with input, then process it, then determine the output.

Comment: Thank you I have to come up with the room deminsions

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to do is take input from your user of the length and width of the object. Then you must calculate the sqr ft using the formula :

**Length * Width = # of Sqr ft**

If you want to do this to two houses you will just need to take two inputs for the second house of the length and width and display that homes total area the same way we did to the first house.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SqrFoot {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //creates a scanner object
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //takes input
    System.out.println("Enter the length : ");
    double length = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter the width : ");
    double width = scan.nextDouble();

    //calculates and displays answer
    System.out.println(length*width + " Sqr ft");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this program take input from the user? If it does, you'll want to use a `Scanner` to accept user input, as such:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You can then use the `nextDouble()` method to input the house dimensions, like so:

```
double length1 = input.nextDouble();
```

Then you can calculate the area of each house:

```
double area1 = length1 * width1;
```

Finally, you can use an if-else block to compare the two areas. Here's an example of how you could do it:

```
if (area1 > area2) {
    System.out.println("House 1 is larger than house 2.");
} else if (area1 < area 2) {
    System.out.println("House 1 is smaller than house 2.");
} else {
    System.out.println("House 1 is the same size as house 2.");
}
```

Comment: No I have to put in the sizes

Comment: Then assign values to the variables for the sizes when you declare them.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework, so I'm not going to do it for you, but I will help you with syntax and let you put it all together.

To store a number you need to declare a *variable*. Variables come in all different types. There is a:

- *String* Which like the name suggests, is a string of characters like "Hello World". To declare a String named hello that contains "Hello World", type the following:

  `String hello = "Hello World";`

  Some important things: `String` is capitalized. You will learn why later, but just remember it for now. The stuff you were storing in `hello` started with and ended with a `"`. As you will see, this is only the case for Strings. Finally, like you may already know, almost every line ends with a `;`.
- *char* Which is short for character and stores a single letter (or symbol, but worry about that later). To store the letter 'P' in a variable named aLetter, type the following:

  `char aLetter = 'P';`

  Some important things: `char` like the rest of the variable names I will tell you about, is lowercase. Also, a char starts and ends with an `'`. Next, I stored a capital P which in Java's mind is completely different than a lowercase p (the point I'm trying to make is everything in Java is case sensitive). Finally, even though my variable name `aLetter` is two words, I didn't put a space. When naming variables, no spaces. ever.
- *int* Which is short for integer. An int stores a whole number (no decimal places) either positive or negative (The largest number an int can hold is around 2 billion but worry about that later). To store the number 1776 in an int named aNumber, type the following:

  `int aNumber = 1776;`

  Some important things: this is pretty straightforward, but notice there aren't any `"`'s or `'`'s. In Java `"1776"` is NOT the same as `1776`. Finally, I hope you are noticing that you can name variables whatever you want as long as it isn't a reserved word (examples of reserved words are: int, String, char, etc.)
- *double* Which is pretty similar to int, but you can have decimal points now. To store the number 3.14 in a double named aDecimal, type the following:

  `double aDecimal = 3.14;`
- *boolean* Which is a little harder to understand, but a boolean can only have 2 values: true or false. To make it easier to understand, you can change in your head (not in the code) true/false to yes/no. To store a boolean value of true in a variable named isItCorrect, type the following:

  `boolean isItCorrect = true;`

There are tons more, but that is all you have to worry about for now. Now, lets go to math. Math in Java is pretty self explanatory; it is just like a calculator except times is `*` and divide is `/`. Another thing to make sure of, is that you are storing the answer somewhere. If you type `5-6;` Java will subtract 6 from 5, but the answer wont be saved anywhere. Instead, do the following:

```
int answer = 0;
answer = 5-6;
```

Now, the result (-1) will be saved in the int named answer so you can use it later.

Finally, we have decision making. In computer science, you change sentences like "If the person's age is at least 21, let them into the bar. otherwise, don't let them in." In decision making, you need to turn all of your questions into yes/no questions. When you need to decide a yes/no question, use what are called *if* statements. The way to write if statements are a little weird: you write the word `if` then you ask your question in parentheses and you *don't* but a `;`. Instead you put a set of curly braces `{}`, inside which you write your code that will run if the question in the if statement is true. For example, the bar example above would be, in code, the following:

```
int age = 25;
boolean letHimIn = false;
if(age>=21)
{
   letHimIn = true;
}
```

Now, the question is, how do you ask a question. To do so, you use the following: `<,>,<=,>=,==,!=`. These are called comparators because they the things on either side of them. They do the following: `<` checks if the number on the left is less than the number on the right, `>` checks if the number on the left is greater than the number on the right, `<=` checks less than or equal, `>=` checks greater or equal, `==` checks if the two numbers are equal, and `!=` checks if the two numbers are not equal. So `if(age>=21)` asks the question, is the number stored in age greater or equal to 21? If so, do the code in curly braces below. If not, then skip the code. As one more example, the code checks if age is exactly equal to 21 and if so, set letHimInTheBar to true.

```
int age = 25;
boolean letHimInTheBar = false;
if(age==21)
{
   letHimInTheBar = true;
}
```

Since age is equal to 25 not 21, the code to make letHimInTheBar true never ran which means letHimInTheBar. The final thing to know about decisions is you can use a boolean variable to ask a question directly. In the following example, we are only letting people whose age is NOT equal to 30 into the bar and if we let them into the bar we will print "Welcome to the bar." and if we didn't then we will print "Stay away.". As a reminder `!` in Java means not. Meaning that it will flip true to false and false to true.

```
int age = 25;
int badAge = 30;
boolean letHimIn = false;
if(age!=badAge)
{
   letHimIn = true;
}
if(letHimIn)
{
   System.out.println("Welcome to the bar.");
}
if(!letHimIn)
{
   System.out.println("Stay away.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is homework and you have help me get started.